# How to gap between two buttons in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app two button arranged vertically in LinearLayout. i want to provide a gap between two buttons.  Please provide a solution...

my layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="10dp"
  >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAction1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cool_button"
    android:text = "HiText1"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAction2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cool_button"
    android:text="HiText2"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnAction1"
/>        

</LinearLayout>
```

image

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: you can set  android:layout_marginTop="5dp" or android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a margin (android:layout_marginTop="50dp") to the top of of the second button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="10dp"
 >
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btnAction1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/cool_button"
   android:text = "HiText1"
/>

<Button android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
   android:id="@+id/btnAction2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/cool_button"
   android:text="HiText2"
   android:layout_below="@id/btnAction1"
/>        

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes layout_below is working in relativelayout not in linear layout

Comment: Actually this won't work if your button has a background property set to it. I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

use `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"` on second button.

Answer (score 3):

use this code for your second button

```
<Buttonandroid:id="@+id/btnAction2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/cool_button"
android:text="HiText2"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
/>
```